# Getting a value from the server before executing Javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have a problem with validation on form submit. When the user hits the submit button I want to validate the input with javascript. I also need some data from the server/database for the validation, which could lead to a yes/no popup.

```
<h:commandButton id="Speichern"
                 value="Speichern"
                 onclick="if(!termPflSubmit('#{TermPflBean.flagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase}')) {return false;}"
                 action="#{TermPflBean.speichernAction}"
                 type="submit"
                 rendered="true" />
```

The javascript function pops up a dialog based on the `flagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase`.

```
function termPflSubmit(flagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase) {
    // Some other validation
    if (flagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase) {
        if (!confirm("Really?"))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `isFlagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase()` java method compares values entered into the form fields to corresponding values in the database. The problem here is, that this method is called once the page is loaded, and there are no values entered into the form fields yet. So the value for the flag is always the same and not correct.
I see two options here:
1. I somehow force the jsp framework to update the value for `flagThatComesFromValidationWithDataFromDatabase` either before submit or everytime something is entered into the form. But how do I do that?
2. I do the validation on serverside and trigger the confirm dialog from the server. But how do I do that?
I thought about ajax, but could not find if `f:ajax` or `p:ajax` tags are already supported in jsp 1.1.

Comment: You can write/include Js/Jquery. You can make use of it Like jQuery.ajax(). Very simple example is mentioned in https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp